# Who owns B- registration? China or Taiwan?

Tags: aircraft-registration

Aircraft registration is unique to each aircraft. Each one begins with country code follow by numbers or characters. However wikipedia says that Taiwan and China both use prefix B. So who actually own the right to use prefix B? If two of them do not co-ordinate the use of prefix them there can be two planes of same registration in the sky. So how things work out here.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aircraft_registration
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_aircraft_registration_prefixes

Comment: I assume you're aware of the complicated history of Taiwan being considered (by some) to be a province of China?

Comment: @Ben yes i’m aware of history from WW2 day to the day taiwan gott kicked out of UN security council till now. It’s complicated and out of topic to talk about jere.

Answer (score 4):

From your second link:

> Aircraft registered in the People’s Republic of China traditionally
> have had "B-" followed by four digits.
>
> ```
> B-0000 to B-9999
> ```
>
> Since 2018, the following registration schemes are also in use:
>
> ```
> B-000A to B-999Z (General)
> B-00A0 to B-99Z9 (General)
> B-00AA to B-99ZZ (General)
> ```

And for Taiwan:

> B-00000 to B-99999 after 1990s

so there won't be any confusion, one has 4 digits/characters after the dash, the other 5 digits.

Comment: As a software developer, I wonder if there was ever a confusion/mixup between a `B-ABCD` and a `B-0ABCD` registered aircraft.

Comment: @DeepSpace, everybody knows the registrations are alphanumeric, that is text, and doing partial conversion to number like you suggest would be extremely contorted, so I would say no.